# Is it necessary to cast a enum with a selected value to an int?

Tags: c#, enums

Is it necessary to cast a `enum` with a selected value to an `int`?

`MessageType` is a column in my DB that is of type `int`.

```
.Where(x => x.MessageType == MyEnum.Sms)
```

This code says that it:

> 'Cannot apply operator '==' of type 'int' and ClassLibrary.MyEnum

It works if `enum` is cast to an `int`:

```
.Where(x => x.MessageType == (int) MyEnum.Sms)
```

My enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Sms = 1,
    Email = 2
}
```

Comment: And what's the question? cast to int. enums are not ints, their undelining types **may be** int(it can be short, byte etc' as well).

Comment: What is the type of the enumerable that you do where on ?

Comment: If `x.MyType` is always means to be a `MyEnum`, why is it of type `int`? Additionally, it looks like you're using LINQ - is this EF, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects....?

Comment: I believe the question is "Is there another/better way to compare vs an enum", and I don't believe there is

Comment: @Sayse, casting from int to enum...

Comment: how is that better though?..

Comment: Ok sry maybe could had explained better. Without the "int cast" worked earlier. But then I renamed the column in the DB, and now I have to cast it to int. Cant see the logic with the rename..

Comment: What is `ClassLibrary.MyClass`?  Is MyType a MyClass?  You have too too many types which you are not defining.  I think you need to edit and clean up your question.

Comment: So its been updated! :)

Comment: @DavidLarsson Enums are not int types, so I believe you would have had to cast it either way.

Comment: But if I have a switch (intValue) then on my cases I got enums, like case (MyEnum.Error), say that error got the value of 4. I Shouldn't need to cast that one to a int? But i need to. Here are an example where they dont: http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch-enum

Comment: In that link they are comparing two enums.  No ints involved.  You can do this too if you declare MessageType as an MyEnum.

Answer (score 0):

Enum's underlying type can be any integral type. If you don't indicate one, it will default to int32. The cast is necessary since the enum does not have an explicit equality comparison for integers - only for other enums. It *is* considered best practice to explicitly cast as you are now. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessarily to cast a enum with a selected value to an int?

Not at all necessarily.  You could always cast the int to enum.

```
.Where(x => MyEnum.Sms == (MyEnum)x.MessageType)
```

Alternatively you can you declare MessageType as an MyEnum.  Then there will be no ints involved.